# Extra empty column in the Out-GridView (powershell 4)?

Tags: string, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have the following code snippet:

```html
function MyTestString
{   
    [string]$OutString
    $OutString = 'ABCDEFG'
    #$OutString | Out-GridView -Wait -Title "String inside function"
    
    return $OutString
}
$MyString = MyTestString | Out-GridView -Wait -Title "Getting Extra Column"
```

When I run it in `Powershell`, I get an extra empty column in the grid view. If `Out-GridView` is placed inside the function then there is no empty column. The same thing is happening with `Export-Clixml`.

How can I avoid the empty column in the grid? I would like to know why do I get an empty column in `GridView`.

Here's a screen shot of the extra empty column:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be extra `row` instead of column, and it's caused by the function body. Let's examine it.

```
function MyTestString
{
    [string]$OutString
    $OutString = 'ABCDEFG'
    return $OutString
}

MyTestString     

ABCDEFG
```

Okay, looks like a direct call returns extra row. Is it really so?

```
$o=MyTestString
$o 

ABCDEFG
```

Let's look inside `$o`:

```
$o.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Now we are getting somewhere. The function returns an array. How about its contents?

```
PS C:\> $o[0]


PS C:\> $o[1]
ABCDEFG
```

The zeroth element doesn't contain anything but emptiness. This looks strange, so let's make sure Powershell is using strict mode (which it doesn't do per default. And that is a brain-dead a design decision.)

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 'latest'
MyTestString
The variable '$OutString' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:3 char:13
+     [string]$OutString
+             ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (OutString:String) [], 
RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

Let's see the function body again:

```
{   
    [string]$OutString
    $OutString = 'ABCDEFG'
    #$OutString | Out-GridView -Wait -Title "String inside function"
    
    return $OutString
}
```

Note the `[string]` part? That isn't a varaible declaration. It will return its contents to the pipeline. When Powershell isn't in strict mode, it returns a big fat of nothing - the empty element at `$o[0]`. When in strict mode, Powershell notes that an uninitialized variable is being accessed.

As for a fix, assign a value to `OutString` - unless you were trying to work with parameters.

```
function MyTestString
{   
    [string]$OutString = 'ABCDEFG'
    return $OutString
}
```

Comment: your explanation and analysis are excellent. Thanks a lot.